# how can i put an image with original color in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Could someone help in this problem?
when i add a image to the button the image color is purple ((not the original color of the photo))
i dont know what to do , please help me check the photos below
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a20Mv.png)

[photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQEBO.jpg)

Comment: You need to remove the backgroundTint color and possibly set it to transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Button`, use an `ImageView` instead of the button. You can still add `android:onClick` attribute on `ImageView` and also can set `View.onClickListener` to an `ImageView`.

This is my workaround regarding this problem.